# Quasi-separatedness is affine-local?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[Vakil defines a scheme $X$ to be quasiseparated if the intersection of any two quasicompact opens is quasicompact]

This is part (b) of 7.3.C in Vakil's FOAG: Show that a morphism $\pi$ from a scheme $X$ into a scheme $Y$ is quasiseparated [ For any open affine $Spec(U)\subset Y$, $\pi^{-1}(Spec(U))$ is quasiseparated] if there is a cover of $Y$ by open affine subsets $U_i$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ is quasiseparated.

Part (a) is to prove the same thing for quasicompactness and is straightforward. The hint suggests using the affine communication lemma and I can use that to show that for an arbitrary open subset $Spec(A)$ of $Y$, $\pi^{-1}(Spec(A))$ is finite union of quasiseparated open subsets, but that is clearly not sufficient.

Another approach seems to be to reduce the problem to showing that if $Spec(W)$ is an open subset of $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ and $Spec(V)$ is an open subset of $\pi^{-1}(U_j)$, then $Spec(W)\cap Spec(V)$ is quasicompact. But i'm not even convinced that this is true in general.

Any hints or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably mention the definition that Vakil is using at this point. A lot of people will take "quasiseparated" to mean that the diagonal morphism is quasicompact. They're equivalent, but you're a few chapters away from seeing why.

Comment: Dear John, [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/9813/221) is somewhat related, and the characterization of quasi-separatedness that is discusses may help you.  Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to doing all these problems on quasi-separatedness is to use the magic square (defined in the beginning of Ravi's notes). As an example of its power we prove:

> > **Exercise 1:** Let $f : X \to Y$ be a quasi-separated morphism of schemes. Then for every open affine $W \subseteq Y$ and open affines $U,V \subseteq X$ that map to $W$, we have that $U \cap V$ can be covered by finitely many affines.

We have an open immersion $W \hookrightarrow Y$ which means that $U \times_Y V \cong U \times_W V$; essentially this comes because an open immersion in the category of schemes is a monomorphism. The magic square then says that we have a fiber diagram

[image]

Then because $\Delta$ is quasi-compact, its pullback $\Delta'$ is quasi compact by stability under base change. Thus $U \times_X V$  is the inverse image  under $\Delta'$ of the affine scheme $U \times_W V$ and thus is quasi-compact. But now $U \times_X V \cong U \cap V$ which completes the exercise.

Having completed this we can now prove the result you want:

> > **Exercise 2:** A morphism of schemes $f : X \to Y$ is quasi-separated iff for any affine open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$, we have that $f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)} : f^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ is quasi-separated.

One direction will follow immediately from the fact that quasi-separatedness is stable under base change. For the other direction suppose we have an affine open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)} : f^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ is quasi-compact. We want to show the diagonal $\Delta: X \to X \times_Y X $ is quasi-compact.

Now recall the construction of the fiber product $X \times_Y X$: Since the $U_i$'s cover $Y$, we have that the $f^{-1}(U_i) \times_{U_i} f^{-1}(U_i)$'s cover $X \times_Y X$. Since quasi-compactness is [local on the target](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463281/problem-on-quasi-compact-morphisms-of-schemes) we are reduced to showing the map$$ \Delta : \Delta^{-1}( f^{-1}(U_i) \times_{U_i} f^{-1}(U_i)) \longrightarrow f^{-1}(U_i) \times_{U_i} f^{-1}(U_i)$$
 is quasi-compact.  By similar reasoning as in Exercise 1, $\Delta^{-1}( f^{-1}(U_i) \times_{U_i} f^{-1}(U_i)) = f^{-1}(U_i)$ and by assumption the diagonal  $f^{-1}(U_i) \to f^{-1}(U_i) \times_{U_i} f^{-1}(U_i)$ is quasi-compact. Thus $\Delta : X \to X \times_Y X$ is quasi-compact as claimed so that $f : X \to Y$ is quasi-separated.

Comment: Thanks for answer user38268. At the point in FOAG where this problem is posed, fibre products have yet to be introduced. Still, this seems like a more natural solution.

Answer (score 10):

Okay, figured it out using some of the ideas in Matt E's post:

Suppose we have a cover of $Y$ by affine open subsets $Spec(U_{i})$ such that $\pi^{-1}(Spec(U_{i}))$ is quasiseparated. Given an arbitrary open subset $Spec(A)$ of $Y$, we wish to show that $\pi^{-1}(Spec(A))$ is quasiseparated. Using the affine communication lemma (See FOAG), we can find a cover of $Spec(A)$ by distinguished open subsets $D(f_{1}),\ldots,D(f_{n})$ such that $\pi^{-1}(D(f_{i}))$ is quasiseparated. Recall that an equivalent condition for a scheme $W$ to be quasiseparated is that it must be possible to cover the intersection of any two open affine subschemes with finitely many open affine subschemes. So let $Spec(B)$
  and $Spec(C)$
  be two such open subschemes of $\pi^{-1}(Spec(A))$
  and note that the problem is reduced to the following special case:

$X$
  is the union of two open affine subschemes $Spec(B)$
  and $Spec(C)$
  and $Y=Spec(A)$
 . Let $D(f_{1}),\ldots,D(f_{n})$
  be a finite cover of $Y$
  such that $\pi^{-1}(D(f_{i}))$
  is quasiseparated. We want to show that $X$
  is quasiseperated.

Let $d_{C,i}$
  denote the preimage of $D(f_{i})$
  in $Spec(C)$
  and $d_{B,i}$
  denote the preimage in $Spec(B)$
 . Then the $d_{B,i}$
  and the $d_{C,i}$
  form an affine cover of X
 . Note that $d_{B,i}\cap d_{B,j}$
  is the preimage of $D(f_{i})\cap D(f_{j})=D(f_{i}f_{j})$
  in $Spec(B)$
 , so it is affine. The analogous remark also applies to $d_{C,i}\cap d_{C,j}$
 . Thus it remains to show that $d_{C,i}\cap d_{B,j}$
  can be covered by finitely many affine open subsets: Note that $p\in d_{C,i}\cap d_{B,j}$
  implies $p\in d_{B,i}$
  since we must have $p\in Spec(B)$
  and $\pi(p)\in D(f_{i}),D(f_{j})$
 . Thus $d_{C,i}\cap d_{B,j}=d_{C,i}\cap(d_{B,j}\cap d_{B,i})$
 We know that $d_{B,j}\cap d_{B,i}$
  is a quasicompact (affine, in fact) open subset of $d_{B,i}\cup d_{C,i}$
 , as is $d_{C,i}$
 . Our original assumption tells us that $d_{B,i}\cup d_{C,i}$
  is quasiseperated and it now follows that $d_{C,i}\cap d_{B,j}$
  is quasicompact and can be covered by finitely many affine open sets. Thus, the space X
  is quasiseparated.

Comment: Nice solution which I think can be simplified a bit in the last paragraph: since $$\operatorname{Spec}(B)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(C) =  \bigcup \left(\operatorname{Spec}(B)\cap \operatorname{Spec}(C)\cap  \pi^{-1}(D(f_i))\right) = \bigcup d_{B,i}\cap d_{C,i}$$
it suffices to note that $d_{B,i}\cap d_{C,i}$ is an intersection of affine opens in the quasi-separated set $d_{B,i}\cup d_{C,i}=\pi^{-1}(D(f_i))$.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an argument using the ``Affine communication lemma,'' perhaps more along the lines of what Vakil intended.

We want to show two steps:

1. If $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A))$ is quasi-separated and $f \in A$, then $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A_f))$ is quasi-separated.
2. If $(f_1, \ldots, f_n) = A$ and each $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A_{f_i}))$ is quasi-separated, then $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A))$ is quasi-separated.

Claim 1 is the easier one: an open subset of a quasi-separated scheme is quasi-separated. (Take two quasi-compacts in the open subset and regard them as quasicompacts in the whole space.)

For 2, suppose $U$ and $V$ are two quasi-compact open subsets of $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A))$. We can reduce to the case where $U$ and $V$ lie entirely in $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A_{f_i}))$ and  $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A_{f_j}))$, since each is covered by finitely many open subsets lying entirely in one of the pre-images. Then

$$U \cap V = U \cap \pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A_{f_i})) \cap V = U \cap V_{\pi^{\#}}(f_i)$$

and $V_{\pi^{\#}}(f_i)$ is affine, so this is quasicompact because $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A_{f_i}))$ is quasiseparated.

Comment: ,Could you please elaborate on why "we can reduce it to the case where $U$,$V$ entirely lie in...."

Comment: Choose affine covers for $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A_{f_i}))\cap U$ (call this set $U_i$), these cover form a cover for $U$, so $U$ has an affine cover where each affine open is contained entirely in some $U_i$. (similarly with $U$ replaced by $V$). Now use quasiseperatedness of $\pi^{-1}(\text{Spec}(A_{f_i}))$.

Comment: What's $V_{\pi^\#}(f_i)$ here?

Answer (score 0):

> **Definition 1.** Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a property of schemes. We say that $\mathcal{P}$ is *local on the target*, (LOCT), if for all morphisms of schemes $f:X\to Y$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ has $\mathcal{P}$,
> 2. $f|_{f^{-1}(V)}:f^{-1}(V)\to V$ has $\mathcal{P}$, for all open subsets $V\subset Y$, and
> 3. there exists an open cover $Y=\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i$ such that $f|_{f^{-1}(V_i)}:f^{-1}(V_i)\to V_i$ has $\mathcal{P}$ for all $i\in I$.
>
> **Definition 2.** Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a property of morphisms of schemes. We say that $\mathcal{P}$ is isomorphism-stable if for all morphisms of schemes $f$ having $\mathcal{P}$, it holds $g\circ f$ (resp., $f\circ h$) has $\mathcal{P}$ for all isomorphisms $g$ (resp., all isos $h$) precomposable (resp., postcomposable) with $f$.
>
> *Notation.* Let $\mathcal{P}$ be an isomorphism-stable property of morphisms of schemes. We say that a morphism $f:X\to Y$ of schemes has the property $\Delta_\mathcal{P}$ if $\Delta_f:X\to X\times_YX$ has property $\mathcal{P}$.

The reason to ask $\mathcal{P}$ to be isomorphism-stable is for the fact “a morphism has $\Delta_\mathcal{P}$” to be independent of the choice of fibre product. (Exercise: verify that $\Delta_\mathcal{P}$ is isomorphism-stable as well.)

For example, $\Delta_{\mathcal{P}}$ equals separatedness and quasi-separatedness when $\mathcal{P}$ equals “being a closed immersion” and “being quasi-compact,” respectively.

> **Lemma.** If $\mathcal{P}$ is an isomorphism-stable property that is (LOCT), then so is $\Delta_{\mathcal{P}}$.

From the lemma one deduces that separatedness and quasi-separatedness are (LOCT) from the knowledge that “being a closed immersion” and “being quasi-compact” are (LOCT).

*Proof.* Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes.

Suppose first $f$ has $\mathcal{P}$, let $V\subset Y$ be open and call $U=f^{-1}(V)$. Note that $U\times_Y U=U\times_V U$ is an open subscheme of $X\times_Y X$ (see [01JR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JR)). Since $\Delta_f$ has $\mathcal{P}$, then so does $\Delta_{X/Y}|_{U}:U=\Delta_{X/Y}^{-1}(U\times_V U)\to U\times_V U$, for $\mathcal{P}$ is (LOCT). But this map is $\Delta_{U/V}$.

Conversely, suppose there is an open cover $Y=\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i$ such that $f|_{U_i}:U_i\to V_i$ has $\Delta_\mathcal{P}$ for all $i\in I$, where $U_i=f^{-1}(V_i)$, i.e., $\Delta_{U_i/V_i}$ has $\mathcal{P}$. But $\Delta_{U_i/V_i}$ can be identified with $\Delta_{X/Y}|_{U_i}:U_i=\Delta_{X/Y}^{-1}(U_i\times_{V_i}U_i)\to U_i\times_{V_i}U_i\subset X\times_Y X$. It suffices to argue then that the sets $U_i\times_{V_i}U_i$ cover $X\times_Y X$. This follows from the facts:

1. $U_i\times_{V_i}U_i=p^{-1}(U_i)\cap q^{-1}(U_i)$, where $X\xleftarrow{p}X\times_Y X\xrightarrow{q}X$ are the canonical projections (see [01JR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JR)),
2. $f\circ p=f\circ q$, and
3. the sets $V_i$ cover $Y$. $\square$